# How exactly does Damage Cancel work?

Tags: phantasy-star-online

I read that the *Damage Cancel* effect occurs when two (or more) people attack the same monster at exactly the same time. Attacks are effectless in that case.

I found many threads claiming different things about this effect, so I wonder what is true:

- Does it occur on *every* simultaneous attack? Or is there only a *chance* it happens?
- Is there any way to see/hear/notice that Damage Cancel occurred? Except knowing how much HP a monster has and summing up the displayed damage, or knowing how many attacks are usually sufficient.
- Are *all* attacks effectless, or is *one* of the attacks working?
- You don’t have to actually deal damage for the effect to occur, true? So a 0 damage attack and the techniques Zalure and Jellen (and failed Megid) can damage cancel, too. What about a *miss*?